# Question about pricing differences between AWS and Google AutoML was closed as off-topic, even though it is about software frameworks

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Huge pricing difference between AWS Custom Comprehend Endpoints and Google AutoML Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66078380/huge-pricing-difference-between-aws-custom-comprehend-endpoints-and-google-autom)

This has been incorrectly tagged as a non-programming question, while I believe it to be the contrary, as it is a software framework used by a lot of programmers.

Questions related to billing are quite an abundance on Stack Overflow with helpful answers, and this question should not have been closed for the same reasons.

Comment: Programming questions ask about concrete code or coding techniques, which you didn't in yours. The [help] is pretty informative about that.

Comment: "Is there anything I am missing with respect to hidden prices/benefits?" is off-topic on SO.

Comment: It is probably better suited for [money.se]

Comment: @Tomerikoo not sure if it's suited for Personal Finance, I don't see AWS billing related queries over there, while there are quite a lot on stackoverflow

Comment: @JeanneDark do you feel there is a better way to frame the question, in this case?

Comment: Personally I never encountered a pricing question on SO. If there are any, they should be closed and deleted. SO is for questions about programming, not about prices of programming services...

Comment: I honestly don't see any way to salvage your question and make it on-topic for this site

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are asking a ***pricing*** question, not a **programming** question.

Although you are asking a pricing question about a tool commonly used by programmers, that is not sufficient to make the question on-topic.

As noted in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking for [*customer support with third-party services*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745) (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, please direct your questions to the relevant company/organisation's technical support team.

This is a customer support question. You need to ask the relevant customer support team(s). If they're charging you for the service, they'll be happy to answer your questions about their pricing model.